# How to define an "AWS Backup" Cross-Account-CopyJob with AWS-CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have been implementing our entire infrastructure in AWS CDK 2 for some time now. I create backups with AWS Backup to the local account with level 2 functions of the CDK (BackupPlan, BackupVault, etc.). In the GUI, copying to another account is also offered. In Cloudformation it can also be found (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/API_CopyAction.html).

But I can't find anything about this in the AWS CDK 2 - preferably Level 2 components.

Has anyone already implemented this? Does anyone have a tip?

Thank you & greetings

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you would like the execute cdk apply in a different aws account ?

If it is so, then there are multiple possibilities.

If you are executing it from your local machine, and have credentials to target account = just reconfiguring your aws credentials to access new target account would be enough. If you have booth accounts configured in yours .credential file, just change the "AWS_PROFILE" environment variable for example.

If you are working with pipelines, and want to switch accounts, you have to setup cross account access first.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

After setup is done, you can change accounts with one line in bash

(you need to define the target $role from your setup,

the $sessionName can be just some gibberish (I usually use something from branch or commit)

```
export $(printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%s" $(aws sts assume-role --role-arn $role --role-session-name $sessionName --query "Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]" --output text))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vilius. But applying CDK in other accounts is not the problem. What i am searching for is to deploy a BackupPlan with configurations, that i only found in the GUI (https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/backup -> Backup Plans -> Backup Rule -> Edit -> "Copy to another account's vault" ). I found no Level 2 component in CDK, to add this. Normally it should be part of Interface `BackupPlanRuleProps` but there is nothing like that in it.